# How to export sub-array from the multidimension array by key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$arr = [
['ID'=>1, 'Name'=>'A'],
['ID'=>2, 'Name'=>'B'],
['ID'=>3, 'Name'=>'C']
];
```

Now I want export to array as below without looping through:

```
$arr2 = ['A','B','C']
```

Is there any function to do that?

Thanks

Comment: [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) <- This is what you want ;D

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't run, maybe my PHP version is not supported.

Comment: The question is do you have php 5.5?

Comment: But I found the other solution: $arr2 = array_map(function($v){return $v['Name'];}, $arr); Thanks for your support ^^

Comment: Well technically this is also looping

Answer (score 0):

[`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) does exactly what you want, it takes two input parameters, the array and the key whose values you want to export

Usage:

```
 $exported_values = array_column($array, 'Name');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
$arr = [
['ID'=>1, 'Name'=>'A'],
['ID'=>2, 'Name'=>'B'],
['ID'=>3, 'Name'=>'C']
];


$new= array_column($arr, 'Name');


print_r($new);
?>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(

            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C

)
```